# How to resolve CWE ID 501 trust boundary violation

Tags: java, security, veracode

Veracode is showing violation flaw. Below is code:

```
public boolean saveSession(HttpServletRequest request, UserSession useSession){

    if (request.getSession().getAttribute(
                USER_ATTRIBUTES) == null && useSession!=null){
            request.getSession().setAttribute(USER_ATTRIBUTES,
                useSession);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am receving flaw at this line:
**request.getSession().setAttribute(USER_ATTRIBUTES,
                    useSession);**
Help me how I can validate my custom class object `useSession` to fix this flaw.

Comment: The trust boundary is the imaginary line between you and the client. Or maybe, its the magic circle around your organization. Within the circle most things are trusted. You are writing information to the session object, which gets sent to the \[untrusted\] client. It crosses the imaginary security boundary. Then, the \[untrusted\] client sends it back to you. At that point, its untrusted input. Imagine what could happen if a malicious user changed `Role=User` into `Role=Admin` and sent it back to you.

Comment: @Rajnikant were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same this but in my case its when I set Struts form in the session attribute.